# ec2 instance can't connect to websites

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I created an ec2 instance for web scraping purposes. However, I can't scrape any sites with selenium because I get below error :

> "selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: connection refused" error.

I think this is to do with the security group settings blocking off websites. So I created a new security group according to [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-http-https-ec2/). However, upon doing this, I am not able to ssh into the EC2 instance anymore.

What configuration do I need for my EC2 instance to be able to scrape websites?

Comment: Is this in the default VPC? Does the routing table used by the subnet that the instance is in have an internet gateway? Can you post the rules from the security groups and the routing table?

Comment: you are using selenium in EC2 or outside ?

Answer (score 0):

For accessing SSH you need to modify the security group as in the image below:

[image: SSH SG RULE]

For accessing HTTP(80 port) or HTTPS(443 port) you need to add rules like this:
[image: HTTP or HTTPS Rules]

Check if these two rules are enabled or not. These are all inbound rules.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that you are using Selenium on an Amazon EC2 instance.

Your **Inbound** security group settings are irrelevant for Selenium, but presumably you will want to login to the instance. Thus, your Inbound security group should permit port 22 (for Linux) or port 3389 (for Windows RDP).

To permit the Selenium app on the instance to access the Internet, you could use the default "Allow all" setting for the **Outbound** security group: All Traffic, all ports, Destination = `0.0.0.0/0`

It is possible that the websites you are attempting to scrape have **blocked the IP address range** of Amazon EC2 instances. (Always operate according to a website's conditions of use!) You can test this by connecting to the Amazon EC2 instance and then trying to retrieve some websites, such as:

```
curl www.google.com
```

The contents of an HTML page should be returned.

Then, try it with one of the websites you are intending to scrape to verify that the instance can access that site.

Comment: I tried creating a new internet gateway to my subnet and also doing what you said with allowing all for inbound and outbound. None of this works. However, when I made a google cloud Vm instance and allowed http and https, it works there.

Comment: Do you have prior experience with creating EC2 instances? If you can login to the instance, then the networking side is working fine (just confirm the security group is permitting All outbound access). Were you able to login and use `curl`?